# Pass token using URL header

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, owin, openid-connect, katana

I have a code that authenticate using Azure AD
I'm using openIdConnect Lib to authenticate with azure AD.
The scenario as below:

1. user open the URL of the app.
2. the app redirect user to Azure AD to authenticate
3. get the id token & access token
4. then AzureActiveDirectoryAuthMiddleware get the context and continue the scenario

this scenario is happenning from the UI, i need to know if i need to pass step number 3 (id token & access token) from postman and the middleware will continue the flow, how i can do this flow?
because my app will be used from UI and from postman
Using c# owin

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check/test the middleware(some REST endpoint) functionality using the tokens through Postman, then copy the AccessToken and open Postman, set the Authorization type as Bearer and add the AccessToken as BearerToken and test the REST call.
Please make sure that the token added should start with Bearer (example - Bearer xyzabc)